# adding elements to sorted linked lists

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list, addition

I'm working on single linked lists in which I got a problem with add function which adds integers into sorted way. But my program keeps crashing. I've been working all the night but I couldn't find the problem. Does anyone has any idea about this?

Thank you

```
template<typename T>
class SLList
{
private:

struct Node
{

Node(const T& val= T(), Node* next_ptr=NULL) : data(val), next(next_ptr) { }

// data members
T data;
Node *next;
};


 template<typename T>

void SLList<T>::add(const T& val)
{
 if (find(val)==false)
  {
 Node *curr= head;
 Node* prev=NULL;
  if(head->next==NULL)
  {
      cout<<"head";
      Node *tmp=new Node(val,head->next);
      head->next=tmp;
      return;
  }
  else
  {
  while(curr->data < val && curr!=NULL)
  {
      curr=curr->next;
      prev=curr;
      cout<<"add";
  }

Node *tmp=new Node(val, prev->next);
//head->next=tmp;
  }
}
}    `
```

Comment: If you've been working all night, I'm sure you don't mind telling us where it crashes, or showing the code for Node.

Comment: struct Node
  {
    // constructor
    Node(const T& val= T(), Node* next_ptr=NULL) : data(val), next(next_ptr) { }
 
    // data members
    T data;
    Node *next;
  };

public:
  SLList();
  SLList(const SLList & lst2);
  ~SLList();
  const SLList& operator=(const SLList & rhs);

  int size() const;
  void print() const;
  bool find(const T& val) const;
  void add(const T& val);
  void remove(const T& val);

private:
  Node *head;

};

Comment: Node is the copy constructor and it crashes in while loop.

Comment: Please add the code to the question (click on edit).

Comment: I added the code. Could you please check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, move `prev = curr` forward:

```
while(curr != NULL && curr->data < val) {
  prev = curr;
  curr = curr->next;
  cout << "add";
}
```

Comment: It's only adding the first value. It's not adding the remaining values

Comment: You are missing `prev->next = tmp;` or similar after the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

The `while` exit condition is inverted:

```
while(curr->data < val && curr!=NULL)
```

should be

```
while( curr!=NULL && curr->data < val )
```

If `curr` is `NULL`, it will crash (well, UB to be exact) before it checks for `NULL`.

Comment: It still crashing in the same while loop.

Comment: I have no idea but its going to while loop

Comment: @user1141641 use ideone.com to post code that compiles and exibits the problem. Otherwise, there's no way to tell with the amount of information you're providing. If you want help, you have to put some effort in it as well.

Comment: @user1141641 just go to ideone.com, paste your code, choose C++, and then submit.

Comment: how do we add another application.cpp file for input in ideone?